# passing image to another viewController

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

Is it possible to push a viewcontroller from a subview? I have a subview of (thumbnail) images, horizontally scrolling. I want when pressed to push a view controller (of the large photos). Obviously this needs to be done from the main view in which the subview resides.

I tried just allocating the large photo view controller and pushing it, but that went kaboom.

my first view which have the scrolled image s follow

```
scrollView.h

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBoutlet UIScrollView *scrollView
@Property (strong, nonatomic) PageController *pageController;
```

`scrollView.m`

```
- (void)viewDidload{
   // here my image array
 }
```

and for another viewcontroller my code as the follow

`secondView.h`

`@Property (nonatomic, strong) IBoutlet UIImageView *ImageView;`

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *selectedImage;`

secondView.m

```
-(voide)viewDidload {
   //use tap gesture cod
} 

- (void)singleTapGestureCaptured:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture{

CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:<yourScrollView>];

NSUInteger touchedPage = floorf(touchPoint.x / <yourScrollView>.frame.size.width);
if ([<arrayOfImages> count>] > 1) {

    touchedPage = touchedPage % ([<arrayOfImages> count] - 1);
}

// i don't know what's the code put here to push the image to the second view
```

so please anybody can advice; thanks alot

Comment: only UINavigationController has the push method, you can use it in secondView

Comment: but how can i defined the selected image on the secondView

Comment: Are you using segues on storyboards, or pushing to the navigation stack manually?

Comment: Can you paste the full code?

Comment: i try to use segue with push but i failed to complete the code because i can't define the selectedImage with secondView. so i go to manualy by tapGesure.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/

Comment: but this tutorial for uicollectionView i think this not matching with uiscrollview

Comment: 1. Are you trying to push the tapped image to second view controller?

Comment: by segue; yes but i can't defined the selectedImaged on segue

Comment: you can add the selected images to an `NSMutableArray` then pass it on

Comment: `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showRecipeDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        RecipeDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.recipeName = [recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}`this code for uicollectionview so can anybody help me to replace this code for uiscrollview

Comment: @TheDoctor can you explain more; because i have already `NSArray` can you tell me how to pass it

Comment: @MohamedReda: 1. create a property in your secondViewController, then pass your array somthing like this:- -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        SecondViewController *secondlVC = (SecondViewController
 *)[segue destinationViewController];
        [secondlVC
 setImgArray:yourArray];
    }
}

Comment: and make sure you've set `CustomClass` in your storyboard for that viewController

Comment: so make segue connection between scrollView to the secondView and add the code above; but i didn't clarify about the selectImage

Comment: i try to make a segue connection between scrollView and the uiimage on secondView but i can't; so if you can explain to me more